# La forme « participe passé sans auxiliare »

Tags: conjugaison

Parfois dans des phrases on ne trouve pas l’auxiliaire avant le participe passé du verbe, par exemple:

Je suis en train de chercher les éléments **concernés**
J'ai bien acheté les vêtements **choisis**. 
Je me demande ce qu'est cette forme, comment l'utiliser et quand on fait l'accord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il s'agit du participe passé employé comme adjectif et il se trouve après un nom dans le présent cas ;  il s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec ce nom, qu'il qualifie. L'accord consiste à utiliser les formes genre/nombre du participe correspondant aux forme genre/nombre du nom.

ex.

- L'élève *choisi* reste à l'école après la sortie.
- La maison *choisi**e*** est au bord de la route.
- Les fruits *choisi**s*** sont ensuite coupés en morceaux.
- Les filles *choisi**es*** doivent s'entrainer deux jours par semaine.

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-22784.php

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-18225.php

Le participe passé s'emploie aussi comme un adjectif qualificatif complément circonstanciel, c'est à dire sans nom ; cela est expliqué dans la page suivante.

https://wwwling.arts.kuleuven.be/alfagram/Temps/nperso/partpas/femploi.htm

Comment: Comme tous les adjectifs, il ne se trouve pas nécessairement après un nom. *Désignés par le sort, ils blahblah*.